# Why i got error when i write the coding, df = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\COE-DRONE01\posing.csv')

Tags: syntax, syntax-error

File "C:\Users\COE-DR~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_7600/1138649954.py", line 1
df = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\COE-DRONE01\Desktop\codeAi')
^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Answer (score 0):

The error log say SyntaxError: unicodeescape can't be decoded, change the "_" to something else, or remove it!